# Does VB.Net DateTime match up to SQL DateTime?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime

I am attempting to use VB.NET EntityFramework to add a new record where on of the fields is of the type of DateTime.

Do the two types of DateTime match up to allow direct saving without any cast or formatting?

I.E Should the following work (where table is WidgetResult and I attempt to add a new record)

```
Private Sub AddNewWidgetResultRecord ()
    Dim newWidgetResult As New WidgetResult()
    newWidgetResult.SomeVarChar = "Some widget string"
    newWidgetResult.SomeDateTime = DateTime.Now    ' Would this line be OK?'
    myContext.AddToWidgetResult(newWidgetResult)
    myContext.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```

I have checked a lot of other posts on this but they all seem to concern INSERT queries rather than using the EF provided methods.

Comment: yes, have you tried it? ™

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible, you want SQL Server to be using [`datetime2`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) rather than [`datetime`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) (but it's only available from 2008 onwards).

`datetime` itself has a more limited range (only from 1753 onwards, not from the year 0) and precision (milliseconds values are rounded to the nearest value ending with `0`, `3` or `7`)

`datetime2` (SQL Server) and `DateTime` (.NET) are compatible.

---

How, precisely, you ensure that the database side is using `datetime2` may depend on exactly what form of EF you're using.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. If I don't require the extra precision or dates pre-1753 is their any advantage to using DateTime2? I see MSDN recommends it, but I'm guessing the extra precision takes up more space?

Comment: @Toby - Surprisingly not. If you look at [`datetime`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) and [`datetime2`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) you'll see that the former always takes 8 bytes, whereas the latter takes between 6-8 bytes (depending on the precision you ask for). It just turns out that `datetime` wasn't that efficient for storage.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they formats are compatible. BUT, one thing I would be cautious of, if you are trying to compare the SQL Server DateTime (GetDate()) to the VB DateTime.Now. You CANNOT guarantee that those will be equal.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are *mostly* correct in that the types are compatible, but they are not *exactly* equivalent.

The biggest difference is what Damien described about how `datetime` has limited range and precision, while `datetime2` has the full range of a `DateTime` and variable precision.

And Ganders is correct that you can't guarantee `DateTime.Now == getdate()`.  Mostly this is because of the clock ticking away in between your calls, but also it's possible that `DateTime.Now` is called from a web server and `getdate()` is called from a SQL Server and they are on two different computers.  Their clocks might not be perfectly synchronized, or they might have different time zone settings.

But the other point that has not been discussed is that `DateTime` has its very important `.Kind` property, which is one of three `DateTimeKind` values.  Either `Utc`, `Local`, or `Unspecified`.  A SQL Server `datetime` or `datetime2` does not have this concept.

So if you have a `Utc` or `Local` kind of `DateTime`, when you save and then retrieve it, you will find that it is now `Unspecified`.  In other words - the kind does not survive the round-trip.

By comparison, the related .NET `DateTimeOffset` type will fully round-trip with a SQL Server `datetimeoffset` type.

You can read more about this (and other concerns) in my blog post [The Case Against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).

Comment: Thanks @Matt. Though I dont currently have any need to complete the round trip, I had been starting to wonder about timezone concerns and server times. anybody else reading this Q, I highly recommend clicking through to read Matt's blog post as it is very helpful.